# gcc compiling linking .a file

Tags: gcc, linker, compilation

in my homework i must use this command to compile my program:

gcc -o mtm_rentals -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror -DNDEBUG mtm_ex2.c rentals.c list.c -L -lmtm

what i can change in that line are the files im writing after -DNDEBUG. when i do this the gcc says that there are undefined references to specific functions. now those functions are declared in an .h file and are implemented in a given file called libmtm.a
i concluded that it doesnt recognize libmtm.a, but our homework task says that the -lmtm flag(which is not declared anywhere) is supposed to link libmtm.a to the program.

what am i missing here? am i supposed to implement somehow the -lmtm flag?
thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `.` (single dot) behind the `-L`.

`-lmtm` will link against a `libmtm` library, this is correct. It's not an `-lmtm` flag, it's a `-l` flag concatenated with `mtm`, the library you want to link against. This library is searched in some predefined paths (like `/usr/lib/`) and additionally in the paths given by -L. Assuming `libmtm` lives in your current directory, you need to add that to `-L`, which is done with a `.`.

Comment: i tried with a dot, but still it doesnt recognize the functions... maybe i am supposed to implement -lmtm

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'implement'? What exactly did you mean by 'the -lmtm flag is not declared anywhere'? Do you know what '-lmtm' does?

Comment: i am doing an assignment and it tells us to use the command i mentioned. it also says that -lmtm is linking libmtm.a to the program. i dont know anything beyond that...

Comment: Probably not, because otherwise you wouldn't ask how to 'implement' -lmtm. It doesn't make sense to implement a linker flag. Look up what the -l flag does, because thats what -lmtm is. Don't you have an error message at the very beginnig that the compiler can't find libmtm?

Comment: i tried to run the command without the -L. and only then it says that it cant find lmtm... when i use -L. it doesnt say that it cant find lmtm. the errors are like this: "In function `printCars':
: undefined reference to `mtmPrintCar'"

Comment: The you are likely missing an object or source file. Find the place where mtmPrintCar is _defined_ (the declaration is not sufficent). Find the *.o or *.c file, where mtmPrintCar is defined and add it to the command line.